# DropDownList displaying System.Data.DataRow.View

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am using Visual Studio 2010 along with the Infragistics WebDropDown tool for ASP.NET (which is still new to me). I am using the 'drag-and-drop' approach along with the setup wizards for design and simplicity (although I prefer manual programming).

I have a Web User Control ("ClientSelect.ascx"). Into that form I added the necessary ScriptManager, and I also dropped in a WebDropDown tool. Using the WebDropDown Wizard, I established the WebDropDown's data source (which adds a connection to the database). The Wizard allows you to test the SQL query, and the results I got back are correct.

However, when the site loads, the values are "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of the actual value ("0001","0002" etc.). Is there anyway to "ToString()" these results. I'm just not seeing how my query returns the right results, but the WebDropDown outputs something else.

Here's my code:

```
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>

    <ig:WebDropDown ID="WebDropDown1" runat="server" Width="112px" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="20px">
    </ig:WebDropDown>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString5 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT clientNum FROM myTable">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thank you in advance for any advice.

ANSWER: I changed the query to "SELECT DISTINCT clientNum AS clients FROM myTable". I then added the attribute TextField = "clients". Thanks to MrZulu and ggonslav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place `DataTextField="clientNum"` as an attribute `<ig:WebDropDown ...>`

Comment: You beat me while i tussled with the editor in stack overflow!

Comment: I tried adding this, but it produced the same results. Infragistics has notoriously poor documentation, so it's been hard finding help. I guess I'll set these properties manually in the "code behind". Thank you

Comment: I have to give it to you, yours does look prettier, @tomo it is probably a different syntax, type TextField="clientNum" instead

Comment: That is the correct property but it's still not showing the right results. I even placed this WebDropDown in it's own page (in hopes of avoiding conflicts with other tools) but something is still wrong. Thank you

Comment: I GOT IT!!!! I changed my statement to "SELECT DISTINCT clientNum AS clients FROM myTable" and then TextField = "clients". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the TextField property to **clientNum** .

Here is the link

[Infragristics Help Step 15](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/WebDropDown_Binding_WebDropDown_to_a_Sql_Data_Source.html)

```
<ig:WebDropDown ID="WebDropDown1" runat="server" Width="112px"   
DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="20px"
 TextField ="clientNum" >  
</ig:WebDropDown>
```

Comment: I will try something along those lines, thank you. When I run that query I am getting the correct results (WebDropDown even displays "System.Data.DataRowView" the correct number of times). But again, thank you, I'll post my findings

Comment: Thank you. I came across this help as well. But it's still not working. This WebDropDown is embedded in another Infragistics tool, WebTab. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: I commented on Mr.Zulu's answer regarding the empty page strategy. Still not working properly. Thank you for your help though, it is much appreciated